# Multiple Seasonal Trend Decomposition

Tags: machine-learning, seasonality

I have been reading work on Time-Series Data. It seems that multiple seasonality makes life really hard for data scientists. I was wondering if anyone could point me towards some reading or explain why multiple seasonality is such a big issue?

(P.S - I was reading the paper that proposed the LSTM - MSNet framework)